# Complicated jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I want validated (using jquery validation plugin). Problem is that I need to do some pre-processing of form values before submitting for validation.

For example, one validation case is that the start time the user defines in the form cannot be before right now. I have 2 components that I need to get the values from in order to get the start time.

Here's how I currently capture that:

```
var mtgStart = new Date( startDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ( startDate.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + startDate.getDate() + ' ' + sTime );
```

I have read that I can pass these params (startTime) into the validation like this:

```
var defaults = jQuery.extend( validationPluginDefaults, {
                ignore:'',
                rules: {
                    meetingName:{
                        mtgNameRequired:true
                    },
                    e2: {
                        startTimeInPast:false
                        startTime:mtgStart
                    }
                }
            });

            jQuery( "form[ id='mtg_form' ]" ).validate( defaults );
```

Question is, where do I create the "mtgStart" variable here?

And my validation method would look like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lowerInt", function(value, element, params) {
    var now = new Date();
    var mtgStart =  params[0]:

    return now < mtgStart;
}
```

UPDATE:

I trigger the validation on click of the submit button now; no problem. Problem now is how do I pass arguments to the jquery validation plugin? I've tried using javascript arrays (as I've read), but I'm not able to access it. Here's my code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod( "createMtgInPast", function( val, el, params ){
var now = new Date();
var mtgStart = params[0];

var nowTime = now.getTime();
var setTime = mtgStart.getTime();

return nowTime < setTime;
```

}, "Cannot create meeting in the past." );

And here's my click handler for submit button:

```
$( '#submit_btn' ).click( function( data )
                {   
                    // Concatenate the start/end dates and their times.             
                    var newStart = new Date( startDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ( startDate.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + startDate.getDate() + ' ' + sTime );
                    var newEnd = new Date( endDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ( endDate.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + eTime );

                    var defaults = jQuery.extend( validationPluginDefaults, {
                        rules: {
                            meetingName:{
                                mtgNameRequired:true
                            },
                            e2: {
                                createMtgInPast: true,
                                data:['TEST']
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $( "#mtg_form" ).validate( defaults );
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, here's my updated code:

```
var defaults = jQuery.extend( validationPluginDefaults, {
                        rules: {
                            meetingName:{
                                mtgNameRequired:true
                            },
                            e2: {
                                createMtgInPast: [newStart]
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I was creating a new method and passing the args there; wrong. Pass the args directly into the validation method.